# Pistols and Background Package - figures contain the background

Tags: psfrag

I am using pistols (`\psfragfig`) commands for font substitutions in `.eps` graphic files. In addition I am using the background package to have a graph paper background.  With normal `\includegraphics` there is no problem but when using `\psfragfig` the command pulls the background grid into each picture when creating the `.pdf` file.

Below is the background code used.

```
\def\mygraphpaper{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=0.2in,line width=0.0pt,gray!60!white] (-3.5in,-4.5in) grid (3.5in,4.75in);
%       \draw[step=1.0in,line width=0.01pt,gray!60!white] (-3.5in,-4.5in) grid (3.5in,4.75in);
\draw[thick,gray!80!black] (-3.5in,5.5in) -- (-3.5in,-5.5in);       % left border
\draw[thick,gray!80!black] (3.5in,5.5in) -- (3.5in,-5.5in);     % right border
\draw[thick,gray!80!black] (-4.25in,4.75in) -- (4.25in,4.75in); % top border
\draw[thick,gray!80!black] (-1.167in,5.5in) -- (-1.167in,4.75in);  % left title
\draw[thick,gray!80!black] (1.167in,5.5in) -- (1.167in,4.75in);    % right title
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{
    angle=0,
    contents=\mygraphpaper,
    color=black,
    scale=1,
    opacity=1
}
```

And here is a typical figure

```
\usepackage[ %
    crop=pdfcrop, %
    cleanup={.tex,.dvi,.ps,.pdf,.log,.aux} %
    ]{pstool}
```

followed by

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \psfragfig*[width=0.45\linewidth]{images/MyFigure}
    \caption{A figure.}
    \label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}
```

The result is that each `.eps` that gets converted to `.pdf` includes the full background image as well. Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to finally fix the problem.  By placing a `\NoBgThispage` command at the beginning of each `<figure>.tex` file suppresses the background from processing when going through the initial processing of the figures.